# How to get Focus on EditText which is in Listview?

Tags: android

Here is my issue.

- I have on listView which contains a `textView` and an `EditText`.
- I filled up data perfectly in `listView`.
- My List contains 20 records when i put my tablet in landscape mode it
  shows me 3 records at a time.
- When I'm entering detail of `EditText` in landscape mode it doesn't
  get focused.
- My `listView` shows me the last record in focused.

**So, how to get FOCUSED ON my `EditText?`**

Thanks.

Comment: can you add your source code